# Bash Scripting General Questions (conditionals and variable passing)

Tags: macos, bash

I'm rather new to bash scripting, and Google isn't as useful as I'd like for this. I'm just playing around with a little password entry program in my .bash_profile and have something like this:

```
read PASSWORD
if $PASSWORD != 'pass'; then
    echo "wrong. exiting"
    exit
fi
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I get these errors (darwin on 10.6)...

**EDIT** Sorry about this posting. My browser crashed and I didn't even realize this posted. I ended up figuring it out on my own – again sorry. But thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing square brackets. The if line should be:

`if [ $PASSWORD != 'pass' ]; then`

or even better:

`if [ "$PASSWORD" != 'pass' ]; then`

Which will avoid failure if $PASSWORD is empty.

Comment: If you're writing Bash-specific scripts, it's good to know the differences between `[` and `[[` which provides additional capabilities. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: Thanks! Both of you (and all of you!)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
read PASSWORD
if [ "x$PASSWORD" != "xpass" ] ; then
   echo "Wrong. Exiting."
   exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: The quotes do the job that the "x" is intended for. Unless you're using an older shell that requires that trick, it's best to get away from using the "x".

Comment: At some point I got used to add that just to make sure it worked and now it's added automatically ;-).

Answer (score 2):

You might like to know about two options to the `read` command:

```
-p string
```

> Display a prompt without a trailing newline

and

```
-s
```

> Silent mode. The characters typed by the user are not echoed to the screen.

So for prompting for a password you could do:

```
read -sp "Please enter your password: " PASSWORD
echo
```

[This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/EnglishFrontPage) is an excellent resource.

Comment: Thanks for that link to Greg's Wiki!

Answer (score 2):

use case/esac construct

```
read -p "enter: " PASSWORD
case "$PASSWORD" in
    "pass") echo "ok;;
    * ) echo "not ok";;
esac
```

Edit: For Dennis's qns

```
x=10
y=5
z=1
options=3
expression="$((x> y)) $((y> z)) $((options<=4))"
case "$expression" in
   "1 1 1")
    echo "x > y and y>z and options <=4";;
    *) echo "Not valid";;
esac
```

Comment: Why would you use a `case` when a simple if/then/[else] will suffice?

Comment: because i don't want to care about comparison operators != or == or whatever.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't understand what that means.

Comment: ok, let me ask you back, why would i want to use if/else ? I feel comfortable using case/esac and to me, its neater.

Comment: Okay, "neater" is a valid basis for an opinion. How would you do `if [[ $x > $y && $y > $z && $options <= 4 ]]` using `case`?

Comment: see my edit. And by the way, i don't use case sometimes, if that's what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: `expression="$((x> y && y> z && options<=4))"` and `"1")`, and you could just put the expression in the `case` statement without using a variable.

Comment: and so and so forth... and ? what else do you want to nitpick about?

Comment: and using a variable is up to individual. I feel like it, so i will use it.